# Open Android activity on HTML button click in web view

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an Android program to display an HTML page in a web view. The HTML page exists locally in "asset/www/index.html".

I want to put a button on the HTML page and open a new activity when the button is clicked.

Here is the Java code:

```
public class HelloWebApp extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass url on button click from html like below,

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="quantize.js"></script>

<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My HTML</h1>
<INPUT TYPE="button" value="Test" onClick="window.location='Navigation://OpenNativeScreen'">
</body>
</html>
```

Now you will get the that url in **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method of web view when button click.see the below code,

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView myBrowser;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dropdown_html);
    myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.equals("Navigation://OpenNativeScreen")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }       
   }
 }
```

Comment: LogCat: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory.
In Emulator: Webpage not available...

Comment: where you have put your html file?

Comment: put your file in asstes folder and write the url file:///android_asset/index.html instead of file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Comment: Did that...still same result. "Webpage not available". Its not exiting from the webview. It should exit webview and open a new activity.

Comment: have you remove WWW from the url ?

Comment: Yes. I deleted WWW folder and added the html file to asset folder.

Comment: Just cut the html file, paste it in the "asset" folder and then delete the WWW folder.

Comment: Yes. ' myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");'