# Start new activity on html webview Webpage not available

Tags: android, android-studio

I find this topic and i did same things on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275699/open-android-activity-on-html-button-click-in-web-view).I click the button and,it's stay the browser.It's say " Navigation://OpenNativeScreen Webpage not available ".It's should start to activity.But it didn't.So it's not switch to activity.

```
public class acilisbir extends AppCompatActivity {


    WebView myBrowser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acilisbir);







        myBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.anasayfagetir);
        myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anasayfa.html");







    }


    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals("Navigation://OpenNativeScreen")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,AnaEkran.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And html page.I use button and input for test but i'll use image later instead of this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="quantize.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Full Page Background Image | Progressive</title>

    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        html { 
            background: url(anasayfabuton/bgorg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #page-wrap { width: 400px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; }
        p { font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30px 0; text-indent: 40px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>



 <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #demo-top-bar {
        text-align: left;
        background: #222;
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 6000;
        padding: 20px 0 20px;
    }
    #demo-bar-inside {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons {
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        margin: 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
    #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 302px;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 38px;
        border-radius: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        margin: 0;
        background: url(/images/examples-logo.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .image_left1{
            margin-top: 50%;
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 3%;
        }

    .image_left2{
            margin-top: 50%;
            width: 40%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }   

    .image_left3{
            margin-top: 15%;
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 3%;
        }

    .image_left4{
            margin-top: 15%;
            width: 40%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }


input[type=test] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 728px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
   {

    .image_left1{
            margin-top: 10%;
            width: 40%;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 3%;
        }

    .image_left2{
            margin-top: 10%;
            width: 40%;
            float: right;
            margin-right: 3%;
        }

}



</style>
<INPUT TYPE="test" value="Test" onClick="window.location='Navigation://OpenNativeScreen'">
<img class="image_left1" src="anasayfabuton/1tr.png">
<img class="image_left2" src="anasayfabuton/2tr.png">
<img class="image_left3" src="anasayfabuton/3tr.png">
<img class="image_left4" src="anasayfabuton/4tr.png">



</body></html>
```

UPDATE FOR 2

I'add my manifest

```
<activity android:name="Buy" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="activity_buy" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Use this code in activity

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("Navigation://OpenNativeScreen")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,AnaEkran.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }else if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("activity_buy://Buy")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(acilisbir.this,Buy.class));
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and html

```
<INPUT TYPE="buycr" value="Buycr" onClick="window.location='activity_buy://Buy'">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code into a new project and amended slightly so that it would build.
I then added a breakpoint to the string compare line and ran in debug mode. When the breakpoint is hit I could see that the url actually equaled `"navigation://OpenNativeScreen"` with a lowercase n. See screenshot below:

[image: Android studio screenshot on string compare breakpoint]

One possible solution would be using the `url.equalsIgnoreCase` method so that the case is ignored when compared. The full line would be:

```
if (url.equalsIgnoreCase("Navigation://OpenNativeScreen")) {
```

Comment: Thank you.It's work anymore.I wonder what if i use "abc" or something instead of "Navigation://OpenNativeScreen".It will work or not.

Comment: I would recommend using the application name as the scheme so it is unique to the application. And the action you want it to perform as the path. Eg if the app was called android-app and the action is open the url would be android-app://open

Comment: I use "if (url.equals("buycredit")) {" and html  <"INPUT TYPE="test" value="Test" onClick="window.location='buycredit'">" for my .Buy class but isn't working.I got same error.Can you tell me what it should be exactly ? Thank you.

Comment: You should be using a string similar to a URL. Similar to android deep linking. I would recommend using the app name as the scheme and the action as the domain. Eg app-name://buycredit

Comment: I little googled about deep link and ı think it's sholud be like this.
 <data android:scheme="Myappname" android:host="Mypackagename" /> so 
 <data android:scheme="Exampleapp" android:host="com.my.app" /> and my link will be "Exampleapp://buycredit " for this case.I have want to asking you before the test because my pc is very slow.I hope did right ?

Comment: or  <data android:scheme="Exampleapp" android:host="buycredit" /> Which one is correct ?

Comment: As it’s not actually deep linking you are using, I think it would be acceptable to use either. I would go with the second one. I would also recommend using all lowercase so that you don’t have any case issues like the original question.

Comment: I don't want to start same topic again,so i ask here.Can you check my first message.